# Removing last two words from string

Tags: powershell, replace, split

I would like to remove the last two words from the strings below

[image]

> 'BIOS Update - Hewlett-Packard'

should also be removed, but I got that part working by doing

```
$HPBIOSs.name.replace('BIOS Update - Hewlett-Packard','').trim()
```

Which gives me :

[image]

I got it working by doing:

```
"$(([string]$HPBIOSs.name.replace('BIOS Update - Hewlett-Packard','').Split(" ")[0..($HPBIOSs.name.replace('BIOS Update - Hewlett-Packard','').Split(" ").count-3)]).Trim())"
```

Is there a better way to archive this ? I'm using it in a switch statement, so I would like it in a one liner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex `-replace` for this.

```
$HPBIOSs.name -replace "(\s\S+){2}$"
```

**Explanation:**

- `\s` matches a single white space character
- `\S+` matches any non-whitespace character one or more times (`+`)
- `{2}` matches exactly two times the capture group within the `()`.
- `$` asserts position at the end of string

Comment: Like this ?      `$HPBIOSs.name.replace('BIOS Update - Hewlett-Packard','').trim() -replace "(\s\S+){2}$"`

Comment: That could work if you want to remove `BIOS Update - Hewlett-Packard` as well as the last two words.

Comment: That could also be `$hpbioss.name -replace "BIOS Update - Hewlett-Packard (.*)(\s\S+){2}$",'$1'`, but it probably does not matter that much performance-wise.